# Vba to copy data with name of header from ws1 to ws2

Tags: excel, vba, web-services

I use this code to copy data from ws1 to other ws base of columns header. I need to find lot of columns header, in this code i repeat code for each col header data. what I need a code where i enter all header name & columns range (for paste) in one line to find and paste match complete columns in other ws.

```
Sheets.add After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Filter Data"
Sheets("RawData").Activate
With Sheets("RawData").Rows(1)
'Find "Name,Date,Num,Item,Qty,Sales Price,Amount & etc" in Row 1
    Set na = .Find("Name", lookat:=xlPart)
    Set da = .Find("Date", lookat:=xlPart)
    Set nu = .Find("Num", lookat:=xlPart)
    Set it = .Find("Item", lookat:=xlPart)
    Set qt = .Find("Qty", lookat:=xlPart)
    Set sp = .Find("Sales Price", lookat:=xlPart)
    Set am = .Find("Amount", lookat:=xlPart)
    'If found, copy the column to Sheet (Filter Data)
        Columns(na.Column).EntireColumn.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Filter Data").Range("A1")
        Columns(da.Column).EntireColumn.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Filter Data").Range("B1")
        Columns(nu.Column).EntireColumn.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Filter Data").Range("C1")
        Columns(it.Column).EntireColumn.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Filter Data").Range("D1")
        Columns(qt.Column).EntireColumn.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Filter Data").Range("E1")
        Columns(sp.Column).EntireColumn.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Filter Data").Range("F1")
        Columns(am.Column).EntireColumn.Copy _
        Destination:=Sheets("Filter Data").Range("G1")
    'Else: MsgBox "Name Not Found"
End With
```

Comment: What is your question? Does the code return an error?

Comment: If i use all header name in code then code is too long i need to make it as short as possible. so that i i enter all header name in single line code. so that i will not set all header name for find. It will make loop to make it short. but i don't know how to make it short

Comment: I just posted an answer. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if the following loop, the runs through the filter, works for you:

```
Sub FilterData()
    Dim Header As Variant
    Dim x As Long, i As Long
    Dim FromColumn As Range

    Header = Array("Name", "Date", "Num", "Item", "Qty", "Sales Price", "Amount")

    x = 1

    For i = LBound(Header) To UBound(Header)
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RawData").Rows(1)
            Set FromColumn = .Find(Header(i), after:=.Cells(1, 1), MatchCase:=False)
        End With

        If Not FromColumn Is Nothing Then
            FromColumn.EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Filter Data").Cells(1, x)

        x = x + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You for Help

Comment: @FaizanRoshan No problem. Don't forget to tick the answer button, if my answer worked for you.